# How to cut the dendrogram with varclus in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am using `varclus`from the package`Hmisc` to perform a clustering of variables (my variables are all numeric). However, I can't find a way to get more information about the clusters I obtained. I tried `cutree` from `hclust` but it didn't work. 
The only information on the clusters and the variables contained in them I can get is by visualizing the tree, but it is not very useful...

Does someone know a similar function than `cutree` for `varclus`? Or another function to perform clustering of variables?
I am a new R user so any help is very welcomed!

Here is an example of a dendrogram I want to cut.

```
install.packages('dprep')
library(dprep)
library(datasets)

mxionosphere <- data.matrix(ionosphere)
v <- varclus(mxionosphere)
plot(v)
```

I want to cut the dendrogram I obtain as output.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic question, I was unaware of that. Can you help me migrate this question to Stack Overflow then? Thank you!

Comment: You can flag this question for moderator attention using the "flag" button at the bottom of your post, though I think your question would fare better in SO if you were to add a simple reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `cutree()` for `varclus()` you just need to extract the `hclust` object first. You can also do this using the `ClustOfVar` package with the `hclustvar()` and `cutreevar()` function:

**Using `Varclus()`:**

You can use the `cutree` function, you just have to extract the `hclust` object from `v` first. This works because the clustering done in the `varclus()` function is actually done by `hclust()`. See ?Hmisc::varclus

Then your code can be used as below:

```
library(dprep)
library(datasets)
mxionosphere <- data.matrix(ionosphere)
v <- varclus(mxionosphere)
groups <- cutree(v$hclust, 10)
```

which will output which cluster each variable belongs to, just as it does for `hclust`.

**Using `ClustOfVar` package:**
(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustOfVar/ClustOfVar.pdf)

Similar to `varclus()`, `hclustvar()` will perform hierarchical clustering on variables. You can then use `cutreevar()` to cut the dendogram into `k` groups.

```
libary(ClustOfVar)
h<-hclustvar(mxionosphere)
clusters<-cutreevar(h, k=10)
groups<-clusters$cluster ##extract clusters values similar to cutree()
```